# How to make event listener pull data from another div?

Tags: javascript, events

I need to change the event listening to a class within the product div, but I want the function to still pull the data within the product div.. at the moment it has 'this.open();' so it's trying to find the data within the .available div (as far as I understand...), but it can't obviously. So I need the event listener to happen on click of .available but then search this.DOM.product.

Any idea how I can fix this? I'm not too familiar with DOM

```
  class Item {
      constructor(el) {
        this.DOM = {};
        this.DOM.el = el;
        this.DOM.product = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.product');
        this.DOM.productBg = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__bg');
        this.DOM.available = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.available');
        this.DOM.productImg = this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__img');

        this.info = {
          img: this.DOM.productImg.src,
          title: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__title').innerHTML,
          subtitle: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__subtitle').innerHTML,
          description: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__description').innerHTML,
          price: this.DOM.product.querySelector('.product__price').innerHTML
        };

        this.initEvents();
      }
      open() {
        DOM.details.fill(this.info);
        DOM.details.open({
          productBg: this.DOM.productBg,
          productImg: this.DOM.productImg
        });
      }
      initEvents() {
        this.DOM.available.addEventListener('click', () => this.open());
      }

    };
```

Comment: You don't say why this doesn't work. You say it doesn't, but you don't describe how it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem is that `this` doesn't resolve to the Item instance within the event handler. That's because event handlers are not automatically bound to anything.

If that's the problem, you can fix it easily by explicitly providing a `this` value when you bind the event handler:

```js
this.DOM.available.addEventListener('click', this.open, this);
```

I added a third argument to `addEventListener`; the argument is optional, and controls the value of `this` within the handler function.

Note: I also changed your handler from `() => this.open()` to just `this.open`. The reason is that you can't unbind an anonymous event handler, which means your current impl makes teardown impossible.